# How to get start of or end of week in dart

Tags: datetime, dart

How can I get the start of or end of a week in dart? An example is if three days ago was a Monday, and today is a Wednesday, how can I find the start of the week using dart, that is on Monday

Comment: Check out https://pub.dev/packages/isoweek :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can get the weekday from the DateTime using https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.1/dart-core/DateTime/weekday.html and add/subtract this number from you date:

```
void main() {
  final date = DateTime.parse('2019-10-08 15:43:03.887');
  
  print('Date: $date');
  print('Start of week: ${getDate(date.subtract(Duration(days: date.weekday - 1)))}');
  print('End of week: ${getDate(date.add(Duration(days: DateTime.daysPerWeek - date.weekday)))}');
}

DateTime getDate(DateTime d) => DateTime(d.year, d.month, d.day);
```

**UPDATE**

Please read and upvote the answer from lrn. He knows a lot more about this stuff than me. :)

Answer (score 42):

Dart `DateTime`s have a `weekday` getter which is 1 for Monday and 7 for Sunday. Using that, I would do:

```dart
DateTime mostRecentSunday(DateTime date) =>
    DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day - date.weekday % 7);
```

to get the most recent Sunday (which is the start of the current week if the week starts on a Sunday), and

```dart
DateTime mostRecentMonday(DateTime date) =>
    DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day - (date.weekday - 1));
```

for the most recent Monday (which is then the start of the current week if the week starts on a Monday).

You can generalize to

```dart
/// The [weekday] may be 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, etc. up to 7 for Sunday.
DateTime mostRecentWeekday(DateTime date, int weekday) =>
    DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day - (date.weekday - weekday) % 7);
```

If you are going to be using the results as calendar dates, I'd used `DateTime.utc` as the constructor instead. (Always use UTC for calendar dates, then you can do day-based arithmetic on them safely).

I'd even consider using `DateTime.utc` in *any* case because it avoids any potential issues with a daylight saving that starts at midnight (rare, but with time zones, even unlikely things tend to have happened somewhere at some point).

Comment: so it seems `DateTime` constructor accepts a negative value for the `day` parameter.. I glanced over the documentation but did not find a mention of it and the implementation is 'external', is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 18):

FIRST DAY OF THE WEEK

```
DateTime findFirstDateOfTheWeek(DateTime dateTime) {
    return dateTime.subtract(Duration(days: dateTime.weekday - 1));
}
```

LAST DAY OF THE WEEK

```
DateTime findLastDateOfTheWeek(DateTime dateTime) {
    return dateTime
        .add(Duration(days: DateTime.daysPerWeek - dateTime.weekday));
}
```

LAST DAY OF THE MONTH

```
DateTime findLastDateOfTheMonth(DateTime dateTime) {
    return DateTime(dateTime.year, dateTime.month + 1, 0);
}
```

FIRST DAY OF THE MONTH

```
DateTime findFirstDateOfTheMonth(DateTime dateTime) {
    return DateTime(dateTime.year, dateTime.month, 1);
}
```

LAST DAY OF THE YEAR

```
DateTime findLastDateOfTheYear(DateTime dateTime) {
    return DateTime(dateTime.year, 12, 31);
}
```

FIRST DAY OF THE YEAR

```
DateTime findFirstDateOfTheYear(DateTime dateTime) {
    return DateTime(dateTime.year, 1, 1); }
```

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.1/dart-core/DateTime-class.html

Answer (score 8):

The way you do this will probably depend on what your app's localization is. If you want to treat Sunday as the start of the week, you would do this:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
int currentDay = now.weekday;
DateTime firstDayOfWeek = now.subtract(Duration(days: currentDay));
```

If you are treating Monday as the start, then do this:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
int currentDay = now.weekday;
DateTime firstDayOfWeek = now.subtract(Duration(days: currentDay - 1));
```

## MaterialLocalizations

If you're using Dart in Flutter, you can use the [MaterialLocalizations](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialLocalizations-class.html) class to get the index of the first day of the week (0 = Sunday, 6 = Saturday). This should help you decide which method from above that you should use.

The example given for the [firstDayOfWeekIndex](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialLocalizations/firstDayOfWeekIndex.html) property is a good reference:

```
var localizations = MaterialLocalizations.of(context);
// The name of the first day of week for the current locale.
var firstDayOfWeek = localizations.narrowWeekdays[localizations.firstDayOfWeekIndex];
```

The MaterialLocalizations class comes with a ton of built in methods to format and display DateTimes.

**dateTime**: 2021-01-26 11:21:05.429320

- formatFullDate: Tuesday, January 26, 2021
- formatCompactDate: 01/26/2021
- formatMediumDate: Tue, Jan 26
- formatShortDate: Jan 26, 2021
- formatShortMonthDay: Jan 26
- formatMonthYear: January 2021
- formatYear: 2021

If none of these fit your needs, you can also use the [DateFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) class to specify how the DateTime should be displayed. It's important to note that the DateFormat class indexes days differently where 1 = Monday and 7 = Sunday.

```
DateFormat.yMMMd().format(new DateTime.now()) // Jan 26, 2021
DateFormat(DateFormat.ABBR_MONTH_DAY).format(now) // Jan 26
DateFormat(DateFormat.WEEKDAY).format(now) // Tuesday
```

Comment: The calculation for a week starting from Sunday isn't quite correct since if the current day is already Sunday, it will return the previous Sunday.

Answer (score 4):

## Dart/Flutter – How to find the first date and the last date of a week

#### 1. Find the first date of the week

```
/// Find the first date of the week which contains the provided date.
DateTime findFirstDateOfTheWeek(DateTime dateTime) {
  return dateTime.subtract(Duration(days: dateTime.weekday - 1));
}
```

#### 2. Find the last date of the week

```
/// Find last date of the week which contains provided date.
DateTime findLastDateOfTheWeek(DateTime dateTime) {
  return dateTime.add(Duration(days: DateTime.daysPerWeek - dateTime.weekday));
}
```

#### Testing

```
void main() {
  // Find first date and last date of THIS WEEK
  DateTime today = DateTime.now();
  print(findFirstDateOfTheWeek(today));
  print(findLastDateOfTheWeek(today));

  // Find first date and last date of any provided date
  DateTime date = DateTime.parse('2020-11-24');
  print(findFirstDateOfTheWeek(date));
  print(findLastDateOfTheWeek(date));
}

// Output
2020-11-23 06:54:42.865446
2020-11-29 06:54:42.865446
2020-11-23 00:00:00.000
2020-11-29 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me but @JoeMuller gave an interesting piece of info on the material localizations, which led me to find out that for what i want, sunday in date.weekday should be 0 took a while to figure it out many thanks to joe and @julemand101 I have this for UK calendar starting from sunday and ending on saturday

```
void main() {
   final date = DateTime.parse('2021-08-01');

   print('Date: $date');
   final weekDay =  date.weekday == 7 ? 0 : date.weekday;
   print('Start of week: ${getDate(date.subtract(Duration(days: weekDay)))}');
   print('End of week: ${getDate(date.add(Duration(days: DateTime.daysPerWeek - weekDay - 1)))}');
}

DateTime getDate(DateTime d) => DateTime(d.year, d.month, d.day);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 function:

```
DateTime getStartTimeWeek([DateTime? date]) {
  final currentDate = date ?? DateTime.now();
  final dateTime = DateTime(currentDate.year, currentDate.month, currentDate.day);
  return dateTime.subtract(Duration(days: currentDate.weekday - 1));
}

DateTime getEndTimeWeek([DateTime? date]) {
  final currentDate = date ?? DateTime.now();

  final dateTime = DateTime(currentDate.year, currentDate.month, currentDate.day, 23, 59, 59, 999);
  return dateTime.add(Duration(days: DateTime.daysPerWeek - currentDate.weekday));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code which should work fine in most cases.

We can get start and end of the week like this:-

**To get the first day of the week for a date use the below function.**
Like Sunday (Also known as 7 in WeekDay).

**Read lines of comments in code for code clarifications.**

```
DateTime getFirstDayOfWeek({required DateTime currentDateTime}) {
  // Converting date provided to UTC
  // So that all things like DST don't affect subtraction and addition on date
  DateTime dateTimeInUTC = DateTime.utc(
      currentDateTime.year, currentDateTime.month, currentDateTime.day);

  // Getting weekday for the date
  // For reference Sunday weekday is 7 and Friday weekday is 5
  int currentWeekDayInUTC = dateTimeInUTC.weekday;

  // Getting Date for nearest Sunday from the provided date
  // By going back a number of weekdays from the current date to reach Sunday
  DateTime firstDayOfWeekInUTC;
  // If current date is not Sunday subtract days to reach Sunday
  if (currentWeekDayInUTC != DateTime.sunday) {
    firstDayOfWeekInUTC =
        dateTimeInUTC.subtract(Duration(days: currentWeekDayInUTC));
  }
  // If current date is Sunday use it as the first day of week
  else {
    firstDayOfWeekInUTC = dateTimeInUTC;
  }

  // Converting back the date for Sunday from UTC type to Local
  // You can also use UTC type depending on your use case
  DateTime firstDayOfWeekInLocal = DateTime(firstDayOfWeekInUTC.year,
      firstDayOfWeekInUTC.month, firstDayOfWeekInUTC.day);

  if (currentDateTime.isUtc) {
    return firstDayOfWeekInUTC;
  } else {
    return firstDayOfWeekInLocal;
  }
}
```

**To get the last day of the week for a date use the below function.**
Like Saturday (Also known as 6 in WeekDay).

**Read lines of comments in code for code clarifications.**

```
DateTime getLastDayOfWeek({required DateTime currentDateTime}) {
  // Converting date provided to UTC
  // So that all things like DST don't affect subtraction and addition on date
  DateTime dateTimeInUTC = DateTime.utc(
      currentDateTime.year, currentDateTime.month, currentDateTime.day);

  // Getting weekday for the date
  // For reference Sunday weekday is 7 and Friday weekday is 5
  int currentWeekDayInUTC = dateTimeInUTC.weekday;

  // Getting Date for nearest Saturday from the provided date
  // By going forward a number of weekdays from the current date to reach Saturday
  DateTime lastDayOfWeekInUTC;
  // If current date is not Sunday add days enough to reach Saturday
  if (currentWeekDayInUTC != DateTime.sunday) {
    lastDayOfWeekInUTC = dateTimeInUTC
        .add(Duration(days: DateTime.saturday - currentWeekDayInUTC));
  }
  // If current date is Sunday add days UpTo saturday
  else {
    lastDayOfWeekInUTC = dateTimeInUTC.add(Duration(days: DateTime.saturday));
  }

  // Converting back the date for Sunday from UTC type to Local
  // You can also use UTC type depending on your use case
  DateTime lastDayOfWeekInLocal = DateTime(lastDayOfWeekInUTC.year,
      lastDayOfWeekInUTC.month, lastDayOfWeekInUTC.day);

  if (currentDateTime.isUtc) {
    return lastDayOfWeekInUTC;
  } else {
    return lastDayOfWeekInLocal;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this DateTime extension you can find any day with in the week. When you call this method you have to pass 1 for Monday, 7 for Sunday.

```
extension DateUtils on DateTime {
  DateTime getDay({required int dayOfWeek}) {
    return subtract(Duration(days: weekday - dayOfWeek));
  }
}
```

To get date of the Monday of this week.

```
DateTime.now().getDay(1);
```

To get date of the Sunday of this week.

```
DateTime.now().getDay(7);
```