# dart How to get a week based on time

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I get a week based on time?
For example, is there a way to get a week starting at 7 o'clock on Saturday and ending at 7 o'clock next Saturday?
using dart

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get start of or end of week in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287278/how-to-get-start-of-or-end-of-week-in-dart)

Answer (score 0):

This answer could help you:

[How to get start of or end of week in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287278/how-to-get-start-of-or-end-of-week-in-dart/58287666)