# How get the first day of a week index in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, date

I try to get the first day of the week index on a flutter app by using :

```
    var firstDayOfWeekIndex =
        MaterialLocalizations.of(context).firstDayOfWeekIndex;
```

It's work done to get the first day of the week based on Language and region settings but not with the calendar phone settings.

For exemple, on locale "en_US" first day of week is sunday, but my phone settings calendar is monday. The previous code get Sunday not monday.

How can achieve this ? (I would like a compatibility iOS/Android) ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer :
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287278/how-to-get-start-of-or-end-of-week-in-dart)

In few words, make this:

```
DateTime findFirstDateOfTheWeek(DateTime dateTime) {
return dateTime.subtract(Duration(days: dateTime.weekday - 1));  }
```

Comment: ```now.subtract(Duration(days: now.weekday - 1)).weekday;``` return monday too, but the first day of the week on my phone calendar settings is set on wednesday, it's don't work !